# Adding custom jars to camel-k integration

Tags: kubernetes, apache-camel, minikube

Lets say I have utility jar called **validation.jar**
which can validate some string to be forwarded.

How can I add this validation.jar along with camel-k integration in **minkube**.

example :

```
import com.validation.Util;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        //from("timer:tick").log(Util.validate("dummy message - new"));
        from("timer:tick").log("dummy message - new");
    }
}
```

to get **com.validation.Util** class we need validation.jar available with camel-k. How to provide that.

Comment: There are details in the Camel K docs at: https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/latest/configuration/dependencies.html

Comment: Thanks Clause, But with this solution I am only able to use libraries available in repository . I am not able use my locally build jar

Comment: Does anybody has update on this?

Comment: You need to deploy nexus repo in your kubernetes and install the custom dependencies there. Additionally configure camel k (confgmap/maven config) to use your nexus repo. Camel K builds the routes inside kubernetes so custom dependencies cannot be provided through kamel cli.

Comment: You could use this approach in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844968/6528166

Answer (score 1):

There is just one way of achieving your goal. Store your java classses with pom.xml file for building jar in github repository. After that you can use  Jitpack.io. Jitpack will build and store jar file in its registry. Finally, you can use as dependency on kamel run command.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from camel-k **1.9.x**, it is possible to provide a dependency located in the local filesystem by using the `file://` prefix when specifying the dependency, like the next example:

```
kamel run -d file://path/to/validation.jar MyRoute.java
```